# Integer function in snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run this query in snowflakes, but I keep having the error below. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get the integer value for the ages.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY
FROM Target_quikvalf
WHERE (((Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY) Like '%N') 
   AND ("DATE" (Target_quikvalf.MISSUE) Between '5/1/2020' And '5/31/2020')
   AND (as_integer((Target_quikvalf.MAGE) / 5)*5))


Error Message:
SQL compilation error: invalid type [FLOAT] for parameter 'AS_INTEGER(variantValue...)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT as_integer(5.1);
```

generates

```
SQL compilation error: invalid type [NUMBER(2,1)] for parameter 'AS_INTEGER(variantValue...)'
```

so don't use a function that is intended to "parsing variant data" to truncate you number, instead

cast

```
SELECT 5.1::int;
```

gives:

```
5.1::INT
5
```

given you are not getting the value scaled as you expect, let break it down:

```
SELECT 68 as age
    , age/5 as float_scale
    , float_scale::int as cast_age
    , round(float_scale,0) as round_age
    , trunc(float_scale,0) as trunc_age
    , trunc_age * 5 as scaled_back;
```

gives:

```
AGE FLOAT_SCALE CAST_AGE    ROUND_AGE   TRUNC_AGE   SCALED_BACK
68  13.600000   14          14          13          65
```

casting, and rounding appear to not be what you want, thus TRUNC is the key here

thus your code should be

```
(TRUNC(Target_quikvalf.MAGE / 5) *5)
```

Comment: For some reason, it's still not working. "Select Trunc(68/5)*5" works! But it is not working for the entire column "MAGE"

Comment: @Dgbow what does "does not work" what result are you getting, if you select the intermediate stages like I showed what do you get.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY, (Trunc(Target_quikvalf.MAGE)/5)*5
FROM Target_quikvalf
WHERE ((Trunc(Target_quikvalf.MAGE)/ 5)*5 AND 
      ((Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY) Like '%N') AND
       ("DATE" (Target_quikvalf.MISSUE) Between '5/1/2020' And '5/31/2020'))  ;        It is bringing up the exact age instead of the Trunc

Comment: dear lord stop using some many parens.  your where clause `WHERE ((Trunc(Target_quikvalf.MAGE)/ 5)*5` should be `WHERE (Trunc(Target_quikvalf.MAGE/ 5)*5`  @Dgbow

Comment: BUT you are still filtering in your where clause on data that's is a transform, so in effect the clause is doing nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230609/discussion-between-dgbow-and-simeon-pilgrim).

Answer (score 1):

The placement of where you are applying the function is the issue. Here we are converting the data type before applying the mathematical calculations.

**You'll need to cast the FLOAT to INT can cast it like so:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY
FROM Target_quikvalf
WHERE (((Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY) Like '%N') 
AND ("DATE" (Target_quikvalf.MISSUE) Between '5/1/2020' AND '5/31/2020') 
AND ((cast(Target_quikvalf.MAGE as int) / 5) * 5);
```

**As an alternative, we can try converting the FLOAT to a number using TO_NUMBER.** If Target_quikvalf.MAGE column was a variant data type, then you'd be able to run it like so (in the example below, we are forcing the converted float number to not have a tenths place and can support ages below 1000 since people can be over 100 years old):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY
FROM Target_quikvalf
WHERE (((Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY) Like '%N') 
AND ("DATE" (Target_quikvalf.MISSUE) Between '5/1/2020' AND '5/31/2020') 
AND ((to_number(Target_quikvalf.MAGE, 3, 0) / 5) * 5);
```

Comment: The Query runs, but it's not converting the age as it should. For example, when I did it in access it converts the ages "68 " to "65", but for snowflakes, the ages remains at "68".

Comment: I dont have snowflake in from of me, but I updated the answer to make sure there were spaces between the multiplication sign just to eliminate whether it was interpreting as unary operator of some sort. Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-arithmetic.html

Comment: ok, updated answer with `to_number` version

Comment: @Dgbow Snowflake platform is called ```Snowflake``` NOT ```Snowflakes```